# ngDialog.open is not a function

Tags: angularjs, ng-dialog

when i try to invoke openDialog function form view  i get the following error 
**ngDialog.open is not a function**
here is my code

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular
        .module('app.user')
        .controller('userController', Controller);

    Controller.$inject = ['$rootScope', '$log', 'ngDialog', 'tpl','DataService'];

    function Controller($rootScope, $log,ngDialog,tpl, DataService) {

        var vm = this;
        vm.user = {};
        vm.createUser = function() {
            DataService.createUser(user);
        }
        vm.openDialog = function() {
        $log.log('vm.openDialog is running')
        ngDialog.open({
            template: 'createUser',
            className: 'ngdialog-theme-default'
        })
        }
        activate();


        function activate() {

        }

    }
})();
```

so what might be problem?
thank you .

Comment: have you include dialog.js in your `index.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See fully working demo over here.

You forgot to add `.module('app.user',['ngDialog'])`

```
ngDialog.open(
{
    template: 'createUser',
    className: 'ngdialog-theme-default'
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/dpbE6lgQDxJYZYOXqU6j?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function Controller($rootScope, $log, ngDialog ,tpl, DataService) {

        var vm = this;
        vm.user = {};
        vm.createUser = function() {
            DataService.createUser(user);
        }
        ngDialog.open = function() {
        $log.log('vm.openDialog is running')
        ngDialog.open({
            template: 'createUser',
            className: 'ngdialog-theme-default'
        })
        }
        activate();
```